# Repository Group authentication on settings.xml

Tags: maven, settings, nexus

I'm generating a maven settings.xml for this scenario with nexus:

- my-releases-repo
- my-snapshots-repo

both into my-group and I have a role which allows the user to crud on my-group.

So, in settings.xml is defined the server, with id as my-group and it's corresponding user and passwd. Of course is defined too the repository into an a active profile, as this:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>my-group</id>
      <releases>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <url>http://my.nexus.corp/content/groups/my-group</url>
   </repository>
```

With this configuration the user is able to authenticate to both repositories and download artifact from them, but not to deploy.

Finally the question is: the server authentication provided in settings.xml applies only for read,view methods when it's defined for a repository group?

Of course, if I add servers pointing to each repository-id (without adding these repositories on profile, only keeping my-group) the deploy works.

My idea is to provide a simplier settings.xml using repository group authentication, avoiding to set the password for each server (repo) because it's the same user.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the `<distributionManagement>` stanza in your pom.xml or settings.xml file. You need this if you want to deploy artifacts to your repo.

Note that the credentials you define in your settings.xml file within the `<servers>` stanza is for both repositories, pluginRepositories, and  configuration. You just need to add the extra stuff - for example, here's mine from a standard pom we use as a parent to all of our Maven projects:

```
<repositories>
    <!-- WARNING: If you change the Id of ANY of these repos, you will need to update every settings.xml
        file on every machine including the Hudson CI server. -->
    <!-- NOTE: All of these repositories use externally accessible URLs, but you can override with LAN
        URLs by configuring mirrors in settings.xml -->
    <repository>
        <id>mycorp-release</id>
        <name>Nexus repository for artifact releases</name>
        <url>https://intranet.mycorp.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mycorp-snapshot</id>
        <name>Nexus repository for artifact SNAPSHOTs</name>
        <url>https://intranet.mycorp.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mycorp-plugin-release</id>
        <name>Nexus repository for plugin artifact releases</name>
        <url>https://intranet.mycorp.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <!-- Where to put released artifacts -->
        <id>mycorp-release</id>
        <name>Nexus release artifact deployment repository</name>
        <url>https://intranet.mycorp.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <!-- Where to put snapshot artifacts -->
        <id>mycorp-snapshot</id>
        <name>Nexus snapshot artifact deployment repository</name>
        <url>https://intranet.mycorp.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same id for all servers just fine as long as they are in a different context. I would suggest to use distributionManagement for the release and snapshot deployment both with the same id.

And for reading the jars back in I would just reference the public group to which you add your release and snapshot repositories. Then the settings.xml will just look like it does in the book Repository Management with Nexus:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html